# Azure PaaS SQL password policy

Tags: azure-sql-database

Auditors are asking what the password policy we have configured for SQL "local" users in our Azure PaaS SQL database is. Is there a menu/screen similar to Local Security Policy in Azure SQL similar like there is in SMSS for on-prem installations?

Answer (score 0):

The CHECK_POLICY and CHECK_EXPIRATION options cannot be turned on because they are not supported on Azure SQL Database. If you try to enable them on a login you may get the following error messages:

> Msg 40517, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Keyword or statement option
>   'check_expiration' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
>
> Msg 40517, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Keyword or statement option
>   'check_policy' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

In addition, the MUST_CHANGE security option is not supported on Azure SQL Database. If you try to enable this option on a login you may get below error message:

> Msg 40517, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Keyword or statement option
>   'must_change' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: Interesting. Our DBA built a report that looks like an Azure SQL equivalant of sys.server_principals for an on-prem installation and it's showing we have some SQL_USER accounts which I assumed would follow some kind of "local" Azure SQL password policy. If we can't configure check_policy or check_expiration for the SQL_USER accounts to link them to AD GPO in the traditional sense, which password policy would these accounts follow?

Comment: To my knowledge SQL logins do not support all the options I mentioned above and policies do not apply to them.